# gatsby-plugin-snipcart unable to display labels in the form

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, snipcart

I'm using snipcart to add cart service to my website. However I can't get it to show lables on the form and I'm unable to figure out why.

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong?

I'm using Test API key, is that why? or is there somthing else I'm missing?

```
{
        resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-snipcart',
        options: {
            apiKey: 'YOUR_SNIPCART_KEY'
        }
    }
```

[image: No lables]

Comment: Can you show more of your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is generally caused by a conflict between your website's CSS and Snipcart's CSS.

You'll have to [inspect the labels using developer tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/css) in your browser to determines which files are affecting the labels. you may have to use more specific selectors to not affect those from Snipcart.

Note that you're using the V2 of Snipcart and the [V3 has been available for seven months now](https://docs.snipcart.com/v3/release-notes).